# how get status RDS instance by name with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds, rds

guys
I have specific names of instances and I need to get available/stopped status RDS instance by name with boto3. Example I can get list ALL instances with InstanceId and status as that

```
rds = boto3.client('rds')
response = client.describe_db_instances()
for resp in response['DBInstances']:
    db_instance_id = resp['DBInstanceIdentifier']
    db_instance_status = resp['DBInstanceStatus']
```

but I have names of instances example `d2-pipeline` or `d4-pipeline` and I want just get they status without any cycle

Comment: what do you mean, `without any cycle`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know DBInstanceIdentifier or DBCluserIdentifier to get all the details which you need.

Comment: and how it will be work if I know DBInstanceIdentifier?

Comment: `response = client.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=<name>)     
                           status = response['DBInstances'][0]['DBInstanceStatus']`

Comment: @SudarshanRampuria This helped me :-)